# How to delete a custom metaData which I have added as a component in Managed package

Tags: managed-package, delete, custom-metadata

How to delete a custom metaData which I have added as a component in Managed package?
I dont see any delete button available and when I try to delete via workbench I get insufficient rights error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something you can't currently do (assuming a package version containing the record has been uploaded as "released"). What you can do is add a checkbox field to your type, called something like "inactive", and limit your queries to exclude inactive records.